# Convert an array to a tuple in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array in a `.js` file and I want to use it as a tuple in a `.ts` file. It's a `.js` file because it's used by config files such as `webpack.config.js`. Is it possible to import it as a tuple?

E.g.:

*entityTypes.js:*

```
export default ['foo', 'bar'];
```

*main.ts:*

```
import type entityTypes from 'entityTypes';
typeof entityTypes[number]; // if `entityTypes` is a tuple, this would be 'foo' | 'bar'
```

Comment: Have you added a `*.d.ts` file for your `entityTypes.js` file?

Comment: No, I should've included in the question that the goal is to avoid duplicating the array since I don't want people to update it in only 1 place

Comment: "if `entityTypes` is a tuple, this would be `'foo' | 'bar'`" - sounds like you want to use `keyof` - but I'm not sure how that would work with a `[ string, string ]`.

Comment: Yeah I just realized I could define `entityTypes` as an object and export `Object.keys(entityTypes)`. Then, in TS, I can do `keyof typeof entityTypes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, Typescript does not analyze JS files, and it'll just type anything imported from there as `any` if no other type is given. Therefore it is impossible to type the array as a tuple without retyping all the strings.

However it is possible to export it as a tuple (if the exporting code would be typescript) with `as const`:

```
export default ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
```

It doesn't seem to be officially documented, but [this blogpost](https://mariusschulz.com/articles/const-assertions-in-literal-expressions-in-typescript) describes it in detail.

Comment: In the `.js` file it'll be a warning

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
const myArray = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;

type ArrayToTuple<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>, V = string> = keyof {
    [K in (T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? U : never)]: V
};

type MyTuple = ArrayToTuple<typeof myArray>;


const shouldPass: MyTuple = 'foo';
const shouldFail: MyTuple = 'hello';
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEwLwwNoDkAZiCAQDQwEBG6KBAujOhDKJFANwBQ3UCABwCmMVBgQAVEBICuAgDZCAPBJhCAHlCFgAJqwBKQ9DvDzkaTEugoAlmADmAPkoA1HDGt2n7gNZCEIEQwAN7cAJB4ANIwdjAAFKoaWroGRiZgZmKWdkRCKDAAqo4wAPyFMABcMGBCAG55AJQMVS7cAL48fIIiALKScoruWZLSA8r8woHw5uKOndzs0B4AFiAy8joACiwQVX2yCiK4xKQEPIuwEKvrOgBi6Dbye-2H7gTLQvLyZJxAA)

Comment: That converts to a union, not a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an array and needed a tuple type because called code wants to make sure there is a certain number of elements in the array. My solution was this:

```
function To4Tuple<T>(arr: T[]): [T, T, T, T] | undefined {
  if (arr.length === 4) return [arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]];
  else return undefined;
}
```

Might need more overloads for other lengths.